# programmatically changing konsole font size

Tags: kde, qt, konsole

I use two different konsole font sizes when I'm on my laptop vs when I have an external monitor connected. I'd love to be able to quickly change the font size with a shell script.

So far I've tried to follow some other qdbus examples in this manner:

`` qdbus org.kde.konsole-`pidof -s konsole` /Windows/1 setFontSize 1 10 ``

but setFontSize is not the right method. Is there a suitable method?